# How can I change the IIS-7 configuration for HTTP trace method and .NET trust level using a Powershell Script?

Tags: iis, iis-7

I want to change the IIS-7 configuration of HTTP Trace method and .NET trust level using a PowerShell script.

I have it by using appcmd in cmd prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- .NET Trust Level

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:trust /level:Medium
```

-- HTTP Trace method disabled

```
%systemroot%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config /section:requestfiltering /+verbs.[verb='TRACE',allowed='false']
```

Comment: A little necroing here, but for those wanting a direct PowerShell solution I used this: `&"$env:systemroot\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config /commit:WEBROOT /section:trust /level:Full`. Btw thanks for this!